# Power Series and their sums

Tags: calculus

How to find the sum of [image]

And what are called the sums got by differentiating it and integrating?
I calculated these, but i can't find the name of the sums: 
1)[image]

2)[image]

Comment: It equals $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^n$ which is just a geometric sum which converges as long as $|\frac{x-3}{2}|<1$.  Note that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \frac{1}{1-a}$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I think you mean $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^n$?